# ASP.NET MVC migrating master page - Problems with web control logic

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controls, migration, master-pages, webforms

I'm trying to migrate an existing ASP.NET Webforms 3.5 application into an ASP.NET MVC 3 application. That means, I attempt to convert existing .aspx pages with webcontrols and codebehind recpectively with controller logic and razor views.
At the moment I'm focusing on the master page (to get an analogue layout.cshtml for all other razor views).
For example I've replaced controls like asp:Menu, asp:LoginView with partial views and @Html.Action to invoke the controller action, run some code that has been in the codebehind of that masterpage before and return that partial view.

But now I'm getting lost with many web controls of the masterpage that have been set in/visible, depending on the code behind. For example there are two asp:panels in the master page that have been switched in/visible depending on the visited page.
The problem is that in razor views I don't have web controls and in controllers I cannot set attributes/properties (like private int counter;).
Thus I don't know how to carry on...

I hope you have got some ideas or experience with this situation.
Please ask if any information is missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can either set properties of the Model or ViewData in the Controller and then use these in the Razor view with @if

e.g.

On the controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Foo = IsThisFoo();
    View();
}
```

In the View:

```
@if (ViewBag.Foo) {
    <p>This is foo</p>
}
else
{
    <p>This is bar</p>
}
```

nb: best practice would be to do it as part of a strongly typed Model for the view